# Swift tableview numberOfRowsInSection return nil fatal error Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hello i have tableview and loading items when table numberOFRowsInSection 0 gives fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

My code here

```
var itemsList = [String]()


internal func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
      self.itemsmessage.text = "Listed your last \(itemsList.count) items"

    return itemsList.count
}
```

Giving Error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

When return nil gives this error in self.itemsmessage.text line. Thank you.

Comment: I think itemList array is not getting allocated when nubmerOfRowsInSection gets called.

Comment: @AshishP. so which code change i need ?

Comment: is `itemsList` really an optional? if so, when in the flow of the app are you creating it?

Comment: in viewDidLoad initialize itemList array...

Comment: Apart from the issue you should not put other code than the value to return in `numberOfRowsInSection` because the method could be called quite often even if the value does not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your self.itemsmessage may not be connected to the actual control in your view controller. Check that its connected. To put safe code around that try this.

`if let message = self.itemsmessage {
    message.text = "Listed your last \(itemsList.count) items"
} else {
   print("Seems like your itemsmessage is not connected to a text label")
}`